# Query distinct values from historical database

Tags: kdb

If I run this query on large Historical database without specifying a date, will KDB be smart enough to retrive status values from index and not bring database down?

`select distinct status from trades`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way kdb can possibly tell all the distinct status is by reading from every partition.  Yes this will take a lot of memory but unless you yourself want to maintain a cache of all distinct status, there is nothing else you can do. As previous mentioned an attribute will speed the query up but the query time will still only scale with the number of partitions.

Comment: alternatively (although not a fail-safe method, depending on the distribution of the values across partitions), sampling some and checking those might be a quick heuristic

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve using index, kdb provides 'g#' attribute. Distinct alone can take more time which depends on size of your table(it will be linear search without `g# attribute).

Check this-> http://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#88-attributes

Let's look at simple example:

```
  q) a: 10000000#1 2 3 5
  q) b:`g#a
  q) \ts distinct a
```

68 134217888

```
  q) \ts distinct b
```

0 288

Difference shows that `g# attribute makes a lot of difference in time and space taken during searching. It is because`g# attribute creates and maintains  index on vector.